# Approximating the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^8} dx$

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals, approximation

Integral: $J=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^8}dx$

Consider the following assertions:

$I:J> \frac{1}{4}$ and $II:J< \frac{\pi}{8}$

A. Both are true

B. Only $I$ is true

C. Only $II$ is true

D. Both are wrong

I tried using the Trapezoidal rule and got $J \approx \frac {1}{4}$ but I'm not sure how to prove the inequality/ find out which one is correct.

Comment: A for $I$, you can bound $$\frac{x}{1+x^8} > \frac{x}{2}$$ hence $I$ is true.

Comment: $0.43348649366995551878699758194143535682608768367262\ldots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^1\frac x{1+x^8}dx=\frac12\int_0^1\frac 1{1+z^4}dz>\frac12\int_0^1\frac 1{1+z^2}dz=\frac\pi8>\frac14.$$

(By WA, $J\approx0.433486$.)

Answer (score 4):

A different approach is to recognize $\frac{x}{1+x^8}$ as the sum of an infinite geometric series with $r=-x^8$ and $a_0=x$, which converges given the bounds of the integral.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 x-x^9+x^{17}\;\mathrm{d}x&>\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^8}\; \mathrm{d}x>\int_0^1 x-x^9\; \mathrm{d}x \\
\frac{41}{90}&>J> \frac{2}{5} \\
0.4555&>J>0.4 \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Very interesting approach!

Comment: Equivalently, $\frac{x}{1+x^8}>\frac{x-x^{17}}{1+x^8}=x-x^9$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Albeit the question is looking for an $\underline{approximation}$, it's good to know that there's a *closed expression* for the integral in terms of the *Digamma Function* $\ds{\Psi}$. Namely,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{x \over 1 + x^{8}}\,\dd x} =
\int_{0}^{1}{x - x^{9} \over 1 - x^{16}}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 16}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{-7/8} - x^{-3/8} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 16}\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{-3/8} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{-7/8} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 16}\bracks{\Psi\pars{5 \over 8} -
\Psi\pars{1 \over 8}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{\root{2} \over 16}\bracks{\pi + \ln\pars{3 + 2\root{2}}} \approx 0.4335} \\ &
\end{align}
The *Digamma Functions evaluation* were performed with the
[Gauss Digamma Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss%27s_digamma_theorem).